# Programming tools to calculate physical forces

Tags: libraries, cad

I would like to calculate the forces involved with physical constructions and I am looking for a tool that can do this for me. It would be great if the tool had a programming interface as I would like to use it for automated design.

Comment: You mean like a physics game engine?

Comment: It should calculate more accurate that what I believe the requirements are for game engines. I believe they only need to seem realistic, not calculate correctly.

Comment: Google for "finite element analysis" ?

Comment: Which physical constructions?  Are you looking for, say, stresses in bridges, or bouncing balls?

Comment: One of things I would like to calculate is a new design of a ski lift. Importantly I would like to see how it behaves when the passengers are moving AND there is wind AND the engine does not pull it entirely stable.

Comment: I don't see how it is programming related...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of Finite Element Analysis packages available both commercially and as open-source software. Often you can integrate these directly into your CAD software. See [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_element_software_packages.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_element_software_packages)